# CatBoost interface with C++

Tags: c++, file-format, catboost

I need to interface with CatBoost through C++ to fit models on some dataset I have in RAM (say as a matrix of floats). However, it does not seem to have a C++ (or any API). I am considering using the provided CatBoost binary after storing the data to disk. This is not ideal but I guess it should be okay. However, it seems like it can only accept data in a CSV format, which is extremely inefficient. Am I missing something? Is there a way to give it data in some binary format?

Comment: https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/c-plus-plus-api

Comment: I have seen this. You can read what it says and see that this is an API only for evaluating a model.